# How can i change the stroke color of the progress circle in ng-zorro?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, ng-zorro-antd

In my Angular project I have a dashboard in mind, which shows me different process circles. Depending on the progress I want to change the color of the line.

This is what it looks like right now.
[image: how it looks]
This is how it should look like. 
[image: how it should look]

Unfortunately I cannot change the color with e.g [nzStrokeColor]="'red'".

```
<div class="flex">
  <nz-card class="cards" *ngFor="let card of dashboarcard">
    <nz-card-meta [nzAvatar]="avatarTemplate" [nzTitle]="card.titel" nzDescription="12.01.2019"> </nz-card-meta>
    <ng-template #avatarTemplate>
      <nz-progress [nzStrokeColor]="'red'" [nzWidth]="40" nzType="circle" [nzPercent]="card.percent"></nz-progress>
    </ng-template>
  </nz-card>
</div>
```

Right now it's always blue, no matter what I enter.
Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Many greetings,
Jin

Comment: [nzStrokeColor]="'red'" would give an error on console... nzStrokeColor="'red'" would be needed... but you are correct, I am unable to see the effect on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snvpab

Comment: @AkberIqbal since 7.0.0 there is no compiler error any more. They added [nzStrokeColor]="'red'". You can read that in the last api line.
[https://ng.ant.design/components/progress/en](https://ng.ant.design/components/progress/en)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ng-zorro-antd@1.8.1` you can't change `stroke` attribute for `svg:path.ant-progress-circle-path` since it [was added](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/commit/167a1104eb8a49bbd6433239fafcc20917572af5#diff-95bcd71d73a859fe40389260048cd4c7) only in 7.0.0-rc.0

So I updated your [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uerkrm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and It actually works as intended:

[image]

You can see it changes `stroke` attribute to `red` **BUT**

> **SVG presentation attributes have lower priority than other CSS style rules specified in author style sheets or ‘style’ attributes**.

That means that `stroke="red"` will be overrided by `.ant-progress-circle-path` class and that's what we see in the picture above.

So that the only one way to override it is to override that class.

---

### Here are several ways of how it can be accomplish:

1) Add override to your global styles ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zakewt?file=src/styles.css))

**styles.css**

```
path.ant-progress-circle-path { stroke:red }
```

*Note:* we added element to class so it will have higher specificity that just class so we do not need `!important` here

2) Use `::ng-deep` combinator in `app.component.css ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3mciqp?file=src/app/app.component.css))

**app.component.css**

```
::ng-deep .ant-progress-circle-path { stroke:red;}
```

3) Add the same rule to `app.component.css` presetting `encapsulation` to `ViewEncapsulation.None` for component ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8gbkv?file=src/app/app.component.ts))

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent  {
```

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. Yes, you're right. With the CSS I am able to set the color. The disadvantage is that I am not able to set the color dynamically. It seems to me, this is an architectural problem. It should have been detected during feature development if the color is not settable effectively.
I tried to use ng-style/ng-class, but withou any luck. Can i use ng-style/ng-class in combination with one of your variants?

Comment: Check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ouwnac?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html I replaced that class so we can now set color dynamically

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was trying to achieve. You really helped me a lot. Thank you very much.